# How to format Bootstrap input field right

Tags: html, input, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

My Input fields (type="text") look like this:

[image: input field error]

Edit: @ckuijjer, Code-Example:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="#" name="newForm" id="newForm" class="panel">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend>Form New Sth</legend>
    <div class="form-group" align="left">
      <label for="Name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Input here..." />
      <span id='name-error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" align="left">
      <label for="district">District</label>
      <input type="text" name="district" id="district" class="form-control" />
      <span id='district-error'></span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The Name field has text in it, but one can only see some pixels of it, also the borders of the input field (district) are not visible good. This only happens to text input fields, not for number-types.

The form is in a Meteor project with the package mizzao:bootstrap-3 added.

@ckuijjer: Actually you're right. I am building an App onto the localmarket App, which is a MIT-licensed example-app of the MeteorJS framework:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/localmarket

Here are the stylesheet files:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/localmarket/client/stylesheets

Isn't there a simple solution that will overwrite the global settings?

I thought that someone maybe had this problem before and might know an answer.

Comment: Do you have a html example?

Comment: I've converted your html example into a code snippet, and I don't see the issue occurring. Likely Bootstrap isn't the only CSS and additional CSS breaks the styling of Bootstrap's input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I found a solution:

In the folder `client/stylesheets/globals` I just commented out the whole file `form.import.less`.

Now the input forms are styled like the example above. Thx again, @ckuijjer.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try with css:-

padding:0;

Comment: Tried, doens't work, but tweaking with CSS/LESS should do it, only I just started out with those and don't know how.